# I cannot see decimals when i use read.table from a file

Tags: r, decimal, read.table

I don't see the decimals in my dataframe when i am using data.table

I read the file but i don't see the decimales in column V2 and only one decimal in the column V3

File to read

```
XYZ-COORD-FILE  ,V1.0 ,2019-06-18,                                        ,
GeoSuite XYZ    Markytanivåer patata1.db,                                 ,
1             6401291.3080 150546.5510      4.0000 BH                     ,
NC01          6401753.0035 150411.6163      4.0834 BH                     ,
NC02          6401758.2095 150438.5028      4.8639 BH                     ,
NC03          6401781.8416 150408.9337      4.2241 BH                     ,

df_pxy <- data.frame(read.table(fichero$datapath,skip=2,stringsAsFactors = F),dec=".")
```

Data.frame

```
V1
V2
V3
V4
V5
V6
dec
1   1   6401291 150546.6    4.0000  BH  ,   .
2   NC01    6401753 150411.6    4.0834  BH  ,   .
3   NC02    6401758 150438.5    4.8639  BH  ,   .
4   NC03    6401782 150408.9    4.2241  BH  ,   .
Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries, 7 total columns
```

Comment: Looks like a typo, keep `dec = "."` argument inside `read.table`. No need to wrap it into data.frame, read.table returns data.frame.

Comment: i get the same results. it is other problem i dont know what! thanks anyway

Comment: If you're using data.table, why don't you read the data with `fread`?